# How to stop the jQuery's queue custom task which has setInterval() inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom animating effect task in jQuery queue. And there is a `setInterval` call inside it.

After some time the `stop()` function is being invoked. It removes the callback of currently executing task from the queue and starts executing the next one.

But `setInterval` from the previous effect (which already having been removed) is still running. Where should I place the `clearInterval` to be invoked after cancelling the task with calling the `stop()`?

Here is an example:

```js
$('body')
    .queue(function(next) {
        var i = 0, el = this;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            el.style.backgroundColor = i++ % 2 == 0 ? '#500' : '#050';
            if (i > 5) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                next();
            }
        }, 1000);
    })
    .queue(function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#005';
    });

setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').stop();
}, 1500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/coderlex/tLd9xtjj/

Answer (score 0):

Move your `interval` variable instantiation outside of the queue closure function, then you can clear it whenever you call `stop()`.

```
var interval = null;   

$('body')
    .queue(function(next) {
        var i = 0, el = this;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            el.style.backgroundColor = i++ % 2 == 0 ? '#500' : '#050';
            if (i > 5) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
                next();
            }
        }, 1000);
    })
    .queue(function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#005';
    });

setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').stop();
    if (interval != null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Calling `stop()` from somewhere outside of my plugin will break everything if do so.

Comment: I didn't change where you called `stop()` though. I only added the bit where it calls `clearInterval`.

Comment: I've noticed that. But the code above is just an example. In real world it would be a plugin or a part of some plugin. And it would be ridiculous if my plugin docs said to call some special method just before or after cancelling effects. At least because the client may use some third party libraries that do it and unaware of my plugin.

So I'm searching something like a `dispose()` callback in `rxjs/Observable` but for jQuery tasks.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. The `interval` variable should be a property of your plugin object, or you can just bind it to the global window object if that wouldn't work (i.e. `window.my_interval_id = setInterval(...)`). It doesn't have to be in the global scope, you just need it accessible outside of the interval closure.

Comment: Third party libraries are still be able to call `stop()` for their own needs not knowing of my plugin requirements. And they will be right because the docs says that `stop()` function has to stop currently running effect.

Saying more, all native functions like `slideDown` or `animate` work with it correctly. So there is a mechanism to dispose timers of currently running animation on its cancelling. In other words I'm wondering how they do it and could I use their approach in my own plugin.

Comment: Hah, I get it now. Sorry about that. Unfortunately I don't know how to answer your question. I was looking into [deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) but I'm not sure if it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about official support of this method, but after reading the jQuery sources it seems I've found the solution. There is an undocumented second argument given to the callback function of the queue task. That's the object of the current effect's hooks. The property we need named `stop` accordingly. If set, the closure is called only in case of manual effect stopping by `stop()` or `finish()` methods. It's not being called on clearing or setting new queue.

Here is an example:

```js
$('body')
    .queue(function(next, hooks) {
        var i = 0, el = this;

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            el.style.backgroundColor = i++ % 2 == 0 ? '#500' : '#050';
            if (i > 5) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                next();
            }
        }, 1000);

        hooks.stop = function() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    })
    .queue(function(next) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#005';
        next();
    });

setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').stop();
}, 1500);
```